# How to check if MySQL replication is using SSL

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb

I have a MySQL (actually mariaDB) install that I just started replicating to another server.  I want to ensure that I've setup SSL correctly.  The SSL portion of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` looks like:

```
Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/mysql/newcerts/ca-cert.pem
Master_SSL_CA_Path: /etc/mysql/newcerts/
Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/mysql/newcerts/client-cert.pem
Master_SSL_Cipher:
Master_SSL_Key: /etc/mysql/newcerts/client-key.pem
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
```

Is this typical or show that replication is using SSL?  Is there something else I can check to ensure it's using SSL?  The slave is successfully replicating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspect the relevant traffic with tcpdump/wireshark.

Comment: You know, there might be a better way, but there's something to be said about literally seeing it happening. It's reassuring. +1

Comment: Agreed.  TIL tcpdump.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the slave replication account has SSL requirements on it. Just because the master support SSL, doesn't mean the account is required to use it.

Comment: Agreed and configured that way.

Comment: Then, if the replication is actually working that should be enough, because the master wouldn't let the slave connect with SSL disabled.